# App Service Certificate to another domain

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I have an azure app service certificate which was configured and bound successfully with my azure app service.

We decided to change the domain name so I deleted azure app service and created new app service for the new domain. I want to bind the existing app service certificate with the new app service (i.e. with new domain) but I don't see any option to unbind certificate from previous app service (which is now deleted).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate a new app Service managed certificate on your new app, there’s no need to have access to the old one they auto renew anyway.